# Use <?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?> to track referrals

Tags: variables

I am setting up my wp site and i have it setup like this www.mydomain.com/?ref=AFFILIATEID
thats alright if they land on the page they are directed to but if they go off page onto another one, how do i get the affiliate id to track through the site so that anywhere i put the link www.affiliatelink.com/ it will show who the referer is.

Also is there a way to set a default referer so that if someone came to the site www.mydomain.com it would have a defulat affiliate id set through out the site.

Im using the latest wordpress, self hosted and using the optimizepress theme

Thanks

James

Comment: James, great to have you at WPSE! Have you tried anything yet code-wise for this?

Comment: Hi Brian nope i havent, im not a coder, i can edit files and usually get scripts to do as i need lol. I did look into plugins but none of them are doing what i want, or add too much to the site, so editing files and or url would be the next way for me to go.

James

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**`add_query_arg()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg).

For example, if your query key is "ref", and your query key value is "AFFILIATEID":

```
<?php add_query_arg( 'ref', 'AFFILIATEID' ); ?>
```

If you need to retrieve your query arg value, use [**`get_query_var()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var):

```
<?php get_query_var( 'ref' ); ?>
```

Comment: I tried the code and it didnt work, im using the plugin Exec-PHP so that i can use php code on the site, would it be that plugin, is there a better or recommended one to use?

Ive got this on the site <?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?> this is in the aweber code so i can adtrack it, i can use the adtrack in the aweber email to direct but i cant get the above code to show the ref it just shows the code as thought it were not php code???

Comment: The question is simply not answerable with any greater precision, because you've not posted relevant code.